# minLength textField attribute in Flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, textfield, variable-length

I'm trying to create a password textfield and I want the user to enter at least 8 characters. I really like the way the visible maxLength character counter on textfields work when a maxlength is set, and I was wondering if there is any equivalent for a minimum length. Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific if you use maxLength then you can not enter more characters, want do you want to as if user enter less then 8 character.

Comment: That would be a maxLength. I want to use to have to enter at LEAST 8 characters before submitting. So I want a minLength. MaxLength is native to flutter textfields but I was wondering about a minLength.

Comment: you can show error message using validator of length of textfiled  is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) instead of [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html).

Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895493/8342742):

> For Text Field Validation use TextFormField instead of TextField.
> TextFormField needs to be wrapped with **Form** widget (If there are
> two ore more textformfields you can wrap their parent widget with form
> widget).Form widget requires key and autovalidate boolean (it's
> optional but it's recommended to show message to user when they
> haven't validated and as soon as they validate message stops showing).
> We create two variables and assign it to Form.Then we need a
> **validator** in which we validate according to our requirements.(If you need to add more validations you can add multiple if
> conditions.).Finally on field submitted we check if user has validated
> the form if validated we perform our desired action else we set
> autovalidate variable to true to perform autovalidation.

E.g.

```
TextFormField(
  ...
  validator: (String value) {
    return value.length < 8 ? 'Minimum character length is 8' : null;
  }
)
```